# Finding Solutions to a Simultaneous Linear Equation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Here is the problem I was given: Find integers $a, b, c, d, e, f$ and positive integer $n > 1$ for which there is a solution in real numbers $x$ and $y$ for the simultaneous equations
$$ax + cy = e,\quad 
bx + dy = f,$$

and yet there is not a solution in integers $x$ and $y$ for the simultaneous congruences
$$ax + cy \equiv e \bmod n,\quad
bx + dy \equiv f \bmod n.$$

Here is what I have so far: $ax+cy=e, bx+dy=f$ becomes $(cf-de)x ≡ af – be (\bmod n)$, by multiplying, $ax+cy=e$ by $f$ and $bx+dy=f$ by $e$ and subtracting.  A similar process is used to have a similar equation relating to $y$, $(cf-de)y≡bc-ad (\bmod n)$.  I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I don't think you've done this correctly.  I get $$
(bc-ad)y\equiv (be-af)\pmod n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have$$
\begin{align}
ax+cy&=e \tag 1 \\
bx+dy&=f   \tag 2
\end{align}$$ 
Solving this system gives
$$
\begin{align}
(bc-ad)y &= be-af\\
(bc-ad)x &= cf-de
\end{align}$$

So long as $bc-ad\ne 0,$ we can solve these equations for $x,y\in \mathbf R.$  Now, we can follow the same procedure and get two congruences
$$
\begin{align}
(bc-ad)y &\equiv (be-af) \pmod n\\
(bc-ad)x &\equiv (cf-de) \pmod n\\ 
\end{align}$$

and we will run into trouble if $bc-ad \equiv 0 \pmod n,$ for then the left-hand side will be $0$ and if the right-hand side is non-zero there is no solution.

Now try to find an example.